# Universal way to logout from terminal via dbus

Tags: linux, systemd, session, d-bus

I'm new with `dbus`, and saw different ways to log out from terminal depending on desktop env. But I'm curious is there any way to log out from any desktop env using `dbus` messages?

On GNOME:

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.Logout uint32:1
```

On KDE:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer org.kde.KSMServerInterface.logout int32:0 int32:0 int32:0
```

Is there any command that would work on every desktop env (like using system `dbus`)?

Comment: thank you very much for reply, could you please provide how can it be done on systemd setups?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On `systemd` setups you should be able to forcibly terminate a session via [`logind`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/) `dbus` interface:

```
busctl call org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 \
org.freedesktop.login1.Manager TerminateSession s \
$(loginctl show-user $UID --property=Sessions --value)
```

---

Note that `busctl` was introduced in `systemd` v. `221` - alternatively, on all setups you could run:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 \
/org/freedesktop/login1 'org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.TerminateSession' \
string:c2
```

where `c2` is the session ID, you can get it via

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 \
/org/freedesktop/login1 'org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.ListSessions'
```

which returns something like this:

```
   array [
      struct {
         string "c1"
         uint32 120
         string "gdm"
         string "seat0"
         object path "/org/freedesktop/login1/session/c1"
      }
      struct {
         string "c2"
         uint32 1000
         string "don"
         string "seat0"
         object path "/org/freedesktop/login1/session/c2"
      }
   ]
```

Comment: One more question Please, on My 14.04 ubuntu I have gnome and KDE, on gnome the logout command worked, I checked and I have systemd-logind, on KDE I have that process too, but `ListSessions` returns empty array and logout command doesn't work.

Comment: One more question, :) sorry for being annoying, My problem is that I'm logged in as user A and create process as user B, which creates session for user B, I want to kill session using dbus messages from that process, I downloaded d-feet, and I can see that after session is created `/org/freedesktop/user/1002` is added in system dbus, but using Terminate in it brings error `'GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject: Unknown user'` but using Terminate for user A works fine.

Comment: I'm talking about ubuntu of course.

Comment: @user173408 - also, it doesn't matter if you see `/org/freedesktop/user/[UID]` in d-feet. If `loginctl` (see my updated post) does not report a session ID for that user than it will never work.

Comment: thanks again :). I checked `loginctl` and new users session id is added. As I use Terminate or KILL from d-feet, session disappear, but session is not killed, I even check from `ps -aux` and all the processes are alive. I've even tried to do it from `/org/freedesktop/login1/Manager` and used `TerminateSession` passing it session ID, this time no error occurs, `loginctl` shows me that session is killed but it is not(all proccesses are alive).

Comment: One more question please, Is there any way that I can get env variables of some process or of the session using dbus messages?

Comment: @user173408 - none that I know of...

Comment: I had to `sudo` despite being logged in as the user, but it works.

Comment: @don_crissti: could you kindly explain abit about the arguments, what they are and how you chose them? I had a look at the link you provided, but was ultimately confused! would greatly appreciate it. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: found [this](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dbus-send) and [this](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-send.1.html) it cleared things a lot.

Comment: @don_crissti : Do you know where I can find the exit codes for logind? when I run this code that you kindly provided , I get `-6` as the exit code(returned value) ! I cant find what this means anywhere!

Comment: no it doesnt log me out, it returns `-6`. yes I used my `user-session-id` that I got from `loginctl list-sessions` . I tried searching for dbus-send errors, but I couldnt find anything. then it crossed my mind that it have to be logind itself. I'm clueless here

Comment: @Rika - hmmm... that `-6` looks more like a method reply message to me but I'm just as clueless as you are... What's your setup there (DE,kernel,distro)? The command works fine on Archlinux (KDE and Gnome), if it matters...

Comment: @don_crissti : I'm on ubuntu 18.04 (on a vmware, maybe thats the issue?)