# How to close XServer session via command

Tags: debian, kill, x-server, session, logout

I have a debian 8.5 computer. In order to create new session I run command
`startx`. With this command a new session is created. How can I via command close this session and to return to previous one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kill the master process of the X session. The master process is the one that started out in life as the child of `xinit`, i.e. `~/.xinitrc` (which is typically a shell script). Usually the last thing `.xinitrc` does is to call a window manager or a session manager (e.g. `twm`, `fvwm`, `gnome-session`, …).

To remember the process ID, you can put it in an environment variable. For example, I have this in my `.xinitrc`:

```
export XSESSION_PID="$$"
…
exec my-favorite-window-manager
```

This way, I can exit by using my-favorite-window-manager's “exit” command, or by running `kill $XSESSION_PID` from any shell in this X session.

Alternatively, if you're modern enough to run D-Bus and a D-Bus aware window/session manager, you can let it know that you want to log out by sending it a command over D-Bus. See [Universal way to logout from terminal via dbus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291922/universal-way-to-logout-from-terminal-via-dbus)

Comment: I tested as you wrote - I added to .xinitrc `export XSESSION_PID="$$"`  but when in `that` session I do `kill $XSESSION_PID` I get usage of kil.... So, something is wrong here.

Comment: @Pavel You must have added it in the wrong place then (or else you have something that wipes your environment after the WM starts, which would be weird). Keep in mind that it has to be done before you run the WM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is my .xinitrc `#!/usr/bin/env bash \n
gnome-terminal & \n export XSESSION_PID="$$" \n exec gnome-session`. I showed by `\n` the end of line. When I run  `startx` then a new session is strated and terminal is shown. However, when I do in this terminal `echo $XSESSION_PID` then there is nothing.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I had to export sesion pid before gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I just run

```
killall xinit
```

I don't put anything into $$ because bash uses $$ for the pid of the shell.

Comment: This is good for when the windows manager crash and the xsession doesn't close.

Comment: This will terminate the X session on all virtual consoles which may not be what you want.