# Terminating a session using loginctl

Tags: linux, xfce, xubuntu, loginctl

I am trying to use "loginctl" to terminate a session like below:

```
loginctl terminate-session 1
```

where 1 is session id. But after the command is executed, black screen is observed & I have to click power button of my laptop to shutdown. Basically what I am looking for is a graceful method to get out of this situation. Also, I am working on Xubuntu.

Comment: Your command works fine on archlinux+gnome. There'a also the [`dbus` way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/291922/22142) which works equally well here but as you can see from the comments there ubuntu users are having troubles either way...

Comment: @don_crissti thanks for the update. Also, do you have anything else(more detailed) on this issue being faced by Ubuntu users then that'd be helpful too.

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu so I have no idea why it doesn't work for you guys...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure for Xubuntu, but on Ubuntu, you first presented with gdm login screen on tty1. After you log in, your x11 session is then opened on tty2. When you terminate your session with `loginctl terminate-session`, your x11 session and tty2 are closed and you see black screen. To return back to the login screen you need to switch to tty1 manually with `CTRL+ALT+F1`